# Input(), нe ожидающий нажатия Enter

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Как написать функцию, которая будет ждать ввод одного символа, и после ввода этого символа автоматически продолжать работу кода (не нажимая клавиши Enter)? Например, сейчас я ввожу «w» + enter, чтобы мой персонаж игры переместился на одну клетку вверх, а я хочу реализовать это без enter.

В интернете нашла коды с использованием `getch()` и подключением библиотек `msvcrt`, `sys`, но ни один переписанный код не сработал. Буду благодарна, если поможете!

Comment: Если что-то не сработало - создавайте вопрос, приводите минимальный воспроизводимый пример, указывайте текст ошибки - мы постараемся помочь. Вам следует прочесть следующие разделы справки: 
[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), 
[Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @cauf Спасибо, я ознакомилась со всеми правилами и учла свои ошибки на будущее. В проблеме я уже разобралась, полученный ответ мне помог. Я не знаю, насколько этот вопрос можно считать полезным или глупым, но если Вы считаете, что он не соответствует правилам SO, можете позвать сюда модератора, который его удалит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот решение Вашей проблемы. Вы описали в вопросе, что эта библиотека не сработала, но я попробовал у себя и всё работает. Возможно, Вы что-то не так переписали.

```python
import msvcrt as m
m.getch() # На этом месте программа останавливается и ждёт ввода любого символа, как только символ будет введён, выполнение продолжится БЕЗ НАЖАТИЯ ENTER
```

Comment: Этот код я уже использовала (переписанным без ошибок), и моя программа не делала паузу, а пропускала этот код, как будто его не существует. Но Ваш комментарий натолкнул меня на мысль, что проблема была в чем-то другом. Оказалось, что печатая код в IDLE и запуская его там же, программа ведет себя так, как описала я. Но если запускать код в консоли, он ведет себя так, как мне изначально и нужно было. Спасибо за ответ!